# Can't get image to load in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Can't get a simple image file to load using Vue (using a single-file component with a .vue extension). Here's the code, which I put inside template:

```html
<div><a href=""><img :src="london.jpg"></a></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not using a bind-able value so don't use binding. Change `:src` to `src`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: What is the error you're getting ?

Comment: That's an extremely vague problem description. Does the `london.jpg` file exist in the given location relative to this component? See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

Comment: In your files, what is the location of this `.vue` component? What is the location of the `london.jpg` file?

Comment: <img :src="london.jpg" /> ----> the end tag could be reason />

Answer (score 2):

I'm used to put all images into the public folder, so I don't need webpack to load images.

The path of the image is '/public/assets/img/london.jpg'

So, in any Vue component I can render the image using

```
<div>
   <a href="#">
     <img src="/assets/img/london.jpg" alt="london"/>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also directly require in your template.

```html
<div>
    <a href="#">
        <img :src="require(`@/assets/img/london.jpg`)"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Note that the @ is your src/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

When binding properties, the model or data type must be correct.

To bind :src, it must be a string or data model.

```html
<div> <a href=""><img :src="'london.jpg'"></a></div>
```

or

```html
<div> <a href=""><img src="img"></a></div>
```

or

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      img: require('london.jpg')
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div> <a href=""><img :src="img"></a></div>
```

Comment: I guarantee that last one won't work because the bundler (eg Webpack) won't include the image asset

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You should try it and see. There's a lot of questions on StackOverflow about it too

Comment: I understand. I'll fix it.

Comment: Failed to compile.

./rg-comp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./rg-comp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'london.jpg' in ' '